# NGINX - redirect www.my-domain.com/blog/1234 to blog.my-domain.com/1234

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm currently using the following location block to redirect all requests from `/blog` to `blog.my-domain.com/`:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://blog.dockerhost$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

However, **I would also like to remove the /blog at the end of the URL**. Right now `www.domain.com/blog/1234` turns into `blog.domain.com/blog/1234`, when I really want `blog.domain.com/1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without a rewrite.

```
location ~ ^/blog(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://blog.dockerhost$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*) $scheme://blog.dockerhost$1$is_args$args? permanent;
}
```